# JavaScript arrow syntax: What does the equals sign on the right hand side mean?

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

I am studying JavaScript syntax.  I occasionally see a pattern that confuses me: an equals sign on the right hand side of the arrow.  For example, something like this:

```
.then(data => myVariable = data)
```

I don't know what is going on in that syntax.  It looks like it is taking the value of `data` and assigning it to the variable named `myVariable`. Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 3):

You're right. It's an arrow function (without an accompanying block) that "returns" an assignment expression - in effect doing an assignment of `data`'s value to `myVariable` and returning the right hand side, though that might not be utilized in this case.

In a more simplified case:

```
let foo = 3;
function foobar(callback) {
  const result = callback(5); //call callback with 5 as argument
  console.log(result); //5
}
foobar(five => foo = five); //assigns 5 to foo
console.log(foo); //5
```

This is generally not the most readable option and your question proves this. I would recommend adding a block like so (if you don't intend on actually returning the right hand side value):

```
myPromise.then(data => {
  myVariable = data;
});
```

In which case there is no implicit return of the assignment expression's right hand side and makes the intent clearer. Also, assignments such as what you're doing right with what I assume to an asynchronous promise are not encouraged.

Maybe look into async/await or other new ES features to deal with asynchronous code other than using variable assignments which may run into [some problems if not used correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like arrow syntax makes things clearer to a point, but then the syntax gets less clear if it becomes too terse.  Probably a medium amount of conciseness is optimal for readability.

Comment: @codebeginner Yes. My rule of thumb is to never sacrifice readability for brevity. If a team member or coworker has to spend more than a few seconds trying to understand what the code syntactically does, then you might want to reconsider your terseness.

Comment: @codebeginner to be honest, this isn't too obscure. Assignment (`=`) always returns the value assigned. So, in terms of pure operation, the function should be clear. The problem is *why* you'd do that. I did have to read your example a couple of times because it just makes little sense. So, it's a lack of clarity of purpose. It seems to be more or less [covering this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function?rq=1) old chestnut but in a roundabout way as it uses a promise to take the variable outside the promise.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is called fat arrow function in ES 6 . It is used for many purposes like
1.Arguments
If we want to pass and argument to a function.
Old Syntax :
let sum = function(x,y){ 
                return x+y;
          }
New Syntax with fat arrow 
let sum = (x,y) => x+y; 

//ES5
var setNameIdsEs5 = function setNameIds(id, name) {
  return {
    id: id,
    name: name
  };
};

// ES6
var setNameIdsEs6 = (id, name) => ({ id: id, name: name });
console.log(setNameIdsEs6 (4, "Kyle"));   // Object {id: 4, name: "Kyle"}

Note : Return statement is not required in fat arrow of it is only one line .

2. Anonymous Function.

// ES5
API.prototype.get = function(resource) {
  var self = this;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    http.get(self.uri + resource, function(data) {
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
Using an arrow function, the same result can be achieved more concisely and clearly:

// ES6
API.prototype.get = function(resource) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(this.uri + resource, function(data) {
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
```